# Snackbar leaves a white line on dismissal

Tags: android, layout, android-snackbar

I am showing a Snackbar in my Activity if the user presses a button & EditText is empty i.e. no text...

It works fine but when it dismisses, it leaves a white line at the bottom the View..

Layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior=".utils.SnackbarBehavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#573FAB"
        android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/type_your_tex"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            tools:ignore="Autofill">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/change_text_size"
            app:backgroundTint="#2C2C2C"
            app:fabCustomSize="55dp"
            app:rippleColor="#55ffffff"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/text_size" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/set_wallpaper"
            app:backgroundTint="#2C2C2C"
            app:fabCustomSize="65dp"
            app:rippleColor="#55ffffff"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/wall"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coloring_options"
            app:backgroundTint="#2C2C2C"
            app:fabCustomSize="55dp"
            app:rippleColor="#55ffffff"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pallete"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="@string/banner" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/color_only_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/choose_your_color"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Snackbar is Present:
[image: Snackbar shown]

After Snackbar is dismissed:
[image: Snackbar Dismissed]

I've tried `getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();` but that doesn't work.

I show my Snackbar like this -

```
Snackbar snackbar; 
snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinator), "There's No Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(darkerColor); 
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: The issue seems to be layout oriented. Which layout actually you're using?

Comment: I tested your java code, it worked fine. I think the problem caused because of your layout.

Comment: show xml please.

Comment: @Daniel updated with layout

Comment: @MatinGdz updated with layout